# Varchar vs nvarchar - causing distinct values that we don't consider distinct

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2019 - we have a column called `Entity` which is of type `nvarchar(max)`. The data from this column is inserted from tables on the web as part of an automated process.

In querying for `DISTINCT` values in this column, we only expected one distinct value, but we actually were returned two.  But the two values looked exactly the same inside SQL Server Management Studio.

So we added a `CONVERT(varchar(max))` to the query in a new column, and we were able to see the difference, as follows:

```
Entity          Converted
Security Law    Security Law
Security Law    Security ?Law
```

Does anyone know how or why this different value is occurring, and more importantly, how we can instruct SQL Server to treat these as duplicate values, by only analyzing the `nvarchar` version?

Comment: What does `SELECT UNICODE(SUBSTRING(Entity,10,1)) WHERE <that row>;` yield?

Comment: Difference between `varchar` and `nvarchar` is that the latter supports an extended character set. It's possible that some of the values contain non-alphanumeric characters, accented characters or similar.

Comment: @PeterSmith why aren't such characters visible in the `nvarchar` version?

Comment: It might be a white space character. What does Aaron's query reveal?

Comment: They won't show up in SSMS as that will be converting the stored data for display.

Comment: Actually copy the data from SSMS, the examples you've given us do not have a (hidden) unicode character in the second string.

Comment: There's plenty on the differences between the two; [see](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/write-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) for example.

Comment: No answers to the question above? Have you abandoned this question? If so delete it

Comment: @MartinSmith the issue is still open and we haven't abandoned this question.  I sent Aaron's query to my DBA and he was pulled into a high-priority task before he could get me the answer.  I hope to have it from him this week.

Answer (score 0):

nvarchar() takes Unicode characters into account. Since you are copying data from web, there could be invisible characters.

you can use regex and extract ASCII characters alone and convert it to varchar so you get distinct values.